# Can I define multiple category for one Marker in google maps v3 api?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I would like to offer two kinds of filtering in my Google Map web page.
Each kind is based on different logic:

- the first is based on the location type "house, building, shopping mall..."
- the second is based on a time stamp "when the user visited this place".

What I am able to do now is to show or hide the markers according the location type (using check boxes).

My questions are:

1- How can I show or hide the markers according a time stamp? Using a time line or something like.

2- Can I define two categories for one single marker? like this I can show and hide markers using check boxes like in the case of location type?

For example here is the function that I am using to show and hide markers according to location type:

```
// == shows all markers of a particular location type, and ensures the checkbox is checked ==
function show(category)
{
    var markers = oms.getMarkers();

    for (var i=0; i<markers.length; i++) 
    {
        if (markers[i].mycategory == category)
              markers[i].setVisible(true);
        else
            markers[i].setVisible(false);
    }
    // == check the checkbox ==
    document.getElementById(category+"Box").checked = true;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: It is certainly possible to do this.  What have you tried?  What does your code that "works" (show or hide the markers according the location type) look like?

Comment: Thank you @geocodezip I will add my code to the question

Comment: What I want now is to add another category set each marker, this category is a time stamp, so the user can show and hide markers according to the location type or according to the time stamp.

Comment: And did you try just doing that?  Adding a "markers[i].mytimestamp"? Making a show/hide function that uses that to do what you want?

Comment: Wow... really? I just used an example that i found online, so I thought that "mycategory" is a predefined member of a Marker object :) ... thank you very much for your answer @geocodezip :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `markers[i].mytimestamp` property to the marker

Add show/hide functions that use that to do what you want.